# LISP/CCL: Passing a quotation mark as argument to 'run-program'

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ccl, clozure-cl

What is the correct way of passing a quotation mark as an argument to Clozure CL's *run-program*?
Take the simple example of calling *echo "*, which should return *"*.

However, when I try to run this command by using ccl:run-program as shown below, the following string is returned: "\\" rather than "\"".
Any ideas on how to tackle this issue? The final goal is to pass a string surrounded by quotation marks to the program as argument.

```
 (with-output-to-string (stream)
   (ccl:run-program "echo" (list  "\"") :output stream)
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

When trying your code, I see the following output:

```lisp
Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.12 (v1.12) LinuxX8664

For more information about CCL, please see http://ccl.clozure.com.

CCL is free software.  It is distributed under the terms of the Apache
Licence, Version 2.0.
? (with-output-to-string (stream)
   (ccl:run-program "echo" (list  "\"") :output stream)
 )
"\"
"
?
```

But some characters are escaped in Common Lisp strings, so in order to be sure about what the string holds, here are different options:

```
? (coerce * 'list)
(#\" #\Newline)
```

or,

```
? (describe **)
"\"
"
Type: (SIMPLE-BASE-STRING 2)
Class: #<BUILT-IN-CLASS SIMPLE-BASE-STRING>
Length: 2
0: #\"
1: #\Newline`
```

So as far as I can tell, the output is as desired.